# Why is the number of votes not clickable on this SE site?

Tags: support, user-interface, votes

A few days earlier, I came to know about this feature of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). I am not sure whether it was present earlier also or has been added recently.

The **number** of votes for each question/answer can be clicked and it shows number of UPvotes and DOWNvotes separately.

However this feature is not there here in Unix and Linux site.

I think that feature is good and can be introduced here also.

P.S.: I know I am not a very frequent visitor here, still wanted to put forward the suggestion, because this site along with AskUbuntu has helped me in some real problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That feature is unlocked when you get to a particular level of rep (1000).

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user

There's a browser plugin you can install (I have it installed in Chrome) which "unlocks" this feature independent of what your rep happens to be on an SE site.

This is the stackapp that allows for this feature w/o 1000 rep: [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep).

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the privileges that are unlocked when you have a certain minimum level of rep. It's on a per-site basis, so having the privilege on one site does not automatically provide the same privilege on other sites - unless you already have the requisite rep on the other sites. You are already well past the requirement on Stack Overflow, but have a ways to go on any of the other sites.

The [privileges page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) outlines the available privileges and corresponding rep requirements. The *Established User* privilege requires 1000 rep, which you haven't yet reached on this site.